# анимация встроенных и собственных виджетов

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Первые попытки создать анимацию:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.box=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')#главный бокс 

        self.box2=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')#анимация этого бокса и будет происходить по индексу
        self.box2.add_widget(Label(text='test animation',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.box.add_widget(self.box2)

        #кнопки управления анимацией
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text='left',on_press=self.pressing,size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text='right',on_press=self.pressing,size_hint=(1,.1)))

        return self.box

    def pressing(self,instance):#собственно анимация)))
        if instance.text=='left':
            anim=Animation(x=-1000,t='out_elastic',duration=1)
            anim.start(self.box.children[-1])#обращаюсь к объекту по индексу
        if instance.text=='right':
            anim=Animation(x=0,t='out_elastic',duration=1)
            anim.start(self.box.children[-1])


TestApp().run()
```

Смущает один момент - я пробовал в самом начале указать позицию за экраном для self.box2, а он все равно по центру, а вот уже когда вызываю функцию анимации, Label меняет свою позицию.
Идея такая, что виджет Label вначале находиться за экраном, потом он обновляется по условиям игры и снова возвращается в центр.
Как вариант можно добавить метод, который, я так понял, только после return может изменить позицию Label.

С floatlayout, конечно в этом плане проще, но если пробовать приложение на разных устройсвах, где разные разрешения экрана, то мой виджет появляется в не очень красивых позициях.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Если нужно анимировать какой-либо виджет или контрол, используйте Animation. Желательно, но не обязательно в качестве холста использовать FloatLayout.

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, я еще потренировался и вот что вышло. Возможно не совсем грамотно, но работает и отвечает на вопрос об анимации и размещении других виджетов и т.д.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock


class TextApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.flag=False#этот флаг нужен для триггера

                            #сделал задержку, потому как на распбери пи у меня по нажатию
                            #фиксируется двойное нажатие на кнопку. Не знаю в чем причина,
                            #но других девайсах с этим проблем нет)
        self.clock=Clock.schedule_once(self.open_anim,.2)
        self.clock.cancel()
        self.clock2=Clock.schedule_once(self.open_anim2,.2)
        self.clock2.cancel()

        self.box=FloatLayout()#в некотором роде холст, который нужен для применения анимации

        self.a_box=BoxLayout(padding=10,spacing=10,pos=(0,0),orientation='vertical')#второй холст, где удобнее всего размещать разные объекты
        for i in range(5):
            self.a_box.add_widget(Button(text='some text {}'.format(i)))

        self.box.add_widget(self.a_box)

                            #Выпадающее меню
        self.bl=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',size_hint=(None,None),size=(200,Window.height),pos=(-210,0))
        for i in range(10):
            self.bl.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
        self.bl.add_widget(Label(text='Some text'))
        self.box.add_widget(self.bl)

        self.box.add_widget(Button(text='menu',
                                   on_press=self.pressing,
                                   pos=(Window.width-50,Window.height-50),size_hint=(None,None),size=(50,50)))

        return self.box

    def pressing(self,instance):#триггер
        if self.flag==False:
            self.clock()
        if self.flag:
            self.clock2()

    def open_anim(self,dt):#анимация появления меню
        anim=Animation(pos=(0,0),t='out_elastic',duration=.5)
        anim.start(self.bl)
        self.flag=True

    def open_anim2(self,dt):#анимация исчезновения меню
        anim=Animation(pos=(-210,0),t='out_elastic',duration=.5)
        anim.start(self.bl)
        self.flag=False

TextApp().run()
```